# ¿Porque se cierra el servidor tambien?como hago para que se mantenga abierto?

Tags: java, socket

Es un juego de piedra papel o tijera.La idea es que el servidor este siempre a la espera de que se conecten clientes. Pero por alguna razon terminado el juego se cierra.
Mi servidor

```
public class JS11 {

    protected static boolean listening = true;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String resultado = "";
        int port = 1111;
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        String url = "localhost";
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Connection Socket Creada");
            while (listening) {
                new Hilo(ss.accept()).start();
                System.out.println("conectado");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR EN EL CLIENTE");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

hilo

```
public class Hilo extends Thread {

private Socket s1 = null;
String continuar, cad3, resultado;
int valor;

public Hilo(Socket socket) {
    super("EchoThread");
    this.s1 = socket;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = s1.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os1 = s1.getOutputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        DataOutputStream dos1 = new DataOutputStream(os1);
         System.out.println("Vamos jugar una partida de Piedra Papel Tijera");
            System.out.println("Esperando eleccion");
        while (true) {               
            cad3 = dis.readUTF();
            valor = Integer.valueOf(cad3);
            if (cad3.equals("1") || cad3.equals("2") || cad3.equals("3")) {
                System.out.println("Usuario eligio: " + cad3);
                int eleccion = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 1);
                String objeto = "";
                switch (eleccion) {
                    case 1:
                        objeto = "Piedra";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        objeto = "Papel";
                        break;
                    default:
                        objeto = "Tijeras";
                        break;
                }
                System.out.println("servidor: " + objeto);
                dos1.writeUTF(objeto);
                if (valor == eleccion) {
                    resultado = "Empate";
                } else if (valor == 1) {
                    if (eleccion == 2) {
                        resultado = "Perdiste";
                    } else if (eleccion == 3) {
                        resultado = "Ganaste";
                    }
                } else if (valor == 2) {
                    if (eleccion == 1) {
                        resultado = "Ganas";
                    } else if (eleccion == 3) {
                        resultado = "Pierdes";
                    }
                } else {
                    if (eleccion == 1) {
                        resultado = "Pierdes";
                    } else if (eleccion == 2) {
                        resultado = "Ganas";
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("El resultado es: " + resultado);
                dos1.writeUTF(resultado);
                } else {
                System.out.println("El cliente no eligio la opcion correcta");
            }
                System.out.println("Otra partida elige 'S' o 'N': ");
                continuar = dis.readUTF();
                dos1.flush();                
            if (continuar.compareToIgnoreCase("N") == 0) {
                System.out.println("Fin de partida");
                break;
            }
        }
        is.close();
        s1.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

}

cliente
public class JC11 {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String cad1, cad3;
    String resultado = "";
    String url = "localhost";
    int port = 1111;
    String eleccionServer = "";
    try {
        Socket sc1 = new Socket(url, port);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        InputStream is = sc1.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(isr);
        OutputStream os1 = sc1.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos1 = new DataOutputStream(os1);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Elige una opcion: 1)Piedra 2)Papel 3)Tijera");
            cad3 = bf.readLine();
            dos1.writeUTF(cad3);
            eleccionServer = dis.readUTF();
            if (cad3.equals("1") || cad3.equals("2") || cad3.equals("3")) {
                System.out.println("El Servidor elige: " + eleccionServer);
                resultado += dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("El resultado es: " + resultado);
            } else {
                System.out.println("tiene que elegir una de las opciones");
            }
            System.out.println("Otra partida elige 'S' o 'N': ");
            cad1 = bf.readLine();
            dos1.writeUTF(cad3);
            dos1.flush();
            if (cad1.compareToIgnoreCase("N") == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        dos1.close();
        sc1.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: NO SE ENCONTRO EL SERVIDOR");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Podria estar el error al momento del Break, cuando escoja N se cierra.

Comment: el break rompe el bucle pero no cierra nada

Comment: Todo parece bien con la edición. Depuraste el código a ver si encuentras algo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es meter la llamada a `ss.accept()` dentro de un bucle infinito, junto con toda la lógica que ejecutas al recibir una conexción. La llamada a este método bloquea la ejecución hasta que se reciba una conexión.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String resultado = "";
    int port = 1111;
    int valor;
    String continuar,tipo;
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    String url = "localhost";
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) {
            Socket s1 = ss.accept();

            // Aquí va el resto del código que hace uso del socket 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR EN EL CLIENTE");
    }
}
```

Un consejo que te puedo dar es que metas la lógica de cada socket (conexión) dentro de un hilo puesto que tal y como tienes ahora el programa solo puedes atender una conexión por vez y hasta que esta no termine de hacer su trabajo no podrás recibir otra.

Comment: eso es otro ejercicio ahora mismo solo tiene que atender a uno :P

Comment: Entonces con esto lo soluciones sin complicarte la vida xD

Comment: Si meto el acept en el bucle el cliente no encuentra el servidor

Comment: Mmm, no tiene nada que ver. El hecho de meter la llamada a `accept()` dentro de un bucle lo que hace es que una vez que atiendas una conexión vuelvas a esperar por otra para atenderla. Yo tengo en producción código como ese y funciona sin problema. Revisa bien que ocurre.

Comment: pues ya te digo si meto el acept dentro del while me dice que no encuentra el srevidor si esta fuera si va bien

Comment: Puedes compartir como lo haz hecho?

Comment: te modifico la pregunta con todo lo que le je puesto